# Convert geodetic coordinates to geocentric (cartesian)

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geospatial, unit-conversion

I'd like to retain as much float precision as possible without having to resort to specialized libraries so I need this code to work with only standard modules.

I'm doing this in QGIS where specialized libraries aren't available by default. `numpy` would be OK to use.

Sources for the computations can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion).

## Here is my code:

```
import math

## Ellipsoid Parameters as tuples (semi major axis, inverse flattening)
grs80 = (6378137, 298.257222100882711)
wgs84 = (6378137, 298.257223563)


def geodetic_to_geocentric(ellps, lat, lon, h):
    """
    Compute the Geocentric (Cartesian) Coordinates X, Y, Z
    given the Geodetic Coordinates lat, lon + Ellipsoid Height h
    """
    a, rf = ellps
    lat_rad = math.radians(lat)
    lon_rad = math.radians(lon)
    N = a / math.sqrt(1 - (1 - (1 - 1 / rf) ** 2) * (math.sin(lat_rad)) ** 2)
    X = (N + h) * math.cos(lat_rad) * math.cos(lon_rad)
    Y = (N + h) * math.cos(lat_rad) * math.sin(lon_rad)
    Z = ((1 - 1 / rf) ** 2 * N + h) * math.sin(lat_rad)

    return X, Y, Z
```

## Input:

```
lat = 43.21009
lon = -78.120123
h = 124
print(geodetic_to_geocentric(wgs84, lat, lon, h))
```

## Output:

```
(958506.0102730404, -4556367.372558064, 4344627.16166323)
```

[This online converter](http://www.apsalin.com/convert-geodetic-to-cartesian.aspx) gives the following output:

```
X: 958506.01027304
Y: -4556367.37255806
Z: 4344627.16160147
```

So, quite close for X and Y but slightly different for Z. Is this a rounding error ? If so, on which side ? Is there a better strategy to do the computations that may retain better precision ?

Comment: What are the units of the output? How far off is it, in meters?

Comment: Units are `m` yes. So it's actually very close but I'm just wondering why the Z computation is off after the 4th decimal when X and Y are pretty consistent.

Comment: So, the heights are in agreement to within a tenth of a millimeter, but that's not good enough? What application is this code for?

Comment: Well, it probably is good enough I agree. I want to compute 7 parameters transformation between datums so I need to convert to Geocentric first and I want to make sure I retain maximum precision.

Comment: Also, why no external libraries (except for you don't want to)? Installing e.g. `numpy` is as easy as it gets (it even fits into a comment field: `pip install numpy`) and it would vastly increase the speed of your function (but probably not its accuracy), especially if you need to evaluate this function for many points.

Comment: Because I _really_ want to ? :-) More seriously, I want to do this within QGIS where `sympy`, `bigfloat` and such aren't available by default. `numpy` is actually acceptable as it is available. There won't be a huge amount of points, less than 100 and usually actually around 10~20 max.

Comment: @200_success Not only is it accurate within a tenth of a millimeter in absolute units, it is actually accurate to one part in 10^11 (measured with respect to the value itself), relatively.

Comment: @YeO Fair enough. That short explanation might be a good thing to add to the question.

Comment: @Graipher @200_success 7 parameters transformation are usually given with 3 decimals (so `mm` accuracy with respect to translations) hence my worry to be off at the fifth decimal on the Z value. As errors tend to add, I'd like to ensure it won't creep up to the fourth or third decimal in the final computation.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 8):

I can't explain the discrepancy with the online conversion tool without seeing the source code for the latter.

#### 1. Review

1. The comment for the ellipsoid parameters should give the units for the semi-major axis. Also, I think "reciprocal flattening" would be a better description of the second parameter, given that you use the name `rf` later on in the code.
2. The docstring for `geodetic_to_geocentric` should give the units (degrees) for the latitude and longitude parameters.
3. "Height above ellipsoid" would be a clearer description for the `h` parameter.
4. The parameters to `geodetic_to_geocentric` could be spelled out in full, which would help understand their meaning. Parameter names are documentation too.
5. Comments would help understand the meaning of values like `N`.
6. The expressions `(N + h) * cos(lat)`, `sin(lat)`, and `(1 - 1 / rf) ** 2` are evaluated twice. These could be stored in local variables to avoid duplicated work.

#### 2. Revised code

```
from math import cos, radians, sin, sqrt

# Ellipsoid parameters: semi major axis in metres, reciprocal flattening.
GRS80 = 6378137, 298.257222100882711
WGS84 = 6378137, 298.257223563

def geodetic_to_geocentric(ellipsoid, latitude, longitude, height):
    """Return geocentric (Cartesian) Coordinates x, y, z corresponding to
    the geodetic coordinates given by latitude and longitude (in
    degrees) and height above ellipsoid. The ellipsoid must be
    specified by a pair (semi-major axis, reciprocal flattening).

    """
    φ = radians(latitude)
    λ = radians(longitude)
    sin_φ = sin(φ)
    a, rf = ellipsoid           # semi-major axis, reciprocal flattening
    e2 = 1 - (1 - 1 / rf) ** 2  # eccentricity squared
    n = a / sqrt(1 - e2 * sin_φ ** 2) # prime vertical radius
    r = (n + height) * cos(φ)   # perpendicular distance from z axis
    x = r * cos(λ)
    y = r * sin(λ)
    z = (n * (1 - e2) + height) * sin_φ
    return x, y, z
```

Comment: Thanks. Technically, the value `e2` is not the eccentricity squared, that would be `1 - (1 - 1/rf)  ** 2`. Also, `n` is the `prime vertical radius of curvature`, not the distance from centre (φ is the Geodetic Latitude, not the Geocentric one).

Comment: @YeO: Thanks for the corrections, now fixed.

Comment: There's a reasonable numerical analytic case to be made for evaluating `e2` as `(2 - 1 / rf) / rf`: if using a different ellipsoid which has `rf` very close to `1` or very large, you eliminate potential loss of significance due to subtracting a number very close to `1` from `1`.

Comment: Upvoted just for using greek letters in variable names. This is a severely under-used feature of Python that could help dramatically simplify the correlation between code and traditional math or academic papers.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks, that is actually the kind of advice I was looking for! In this case, rf will usually be ~300 as I'm interested in actual coordinates on earth.

Answer (score 5):

Precision in numeric calculus is usually handled by the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module. Compare:

```
>>> 1.001 + 0.0001
1.0010999999999999
>>> Decimal('1.001') + Decimal('0.0001')
Decimal('1.0011')
```

However, trigonometric functions would convert a `decimal.Decimal` back to a `float`, thus defeating the purpose. However, the `decimal` module provide some [recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#recipes) to help fill the void. Using the recipe for `pi()` you can reimplement `math.radians` easily; `cos()` and `sin()` are covered by the recipes; and `math.sqrt` is [available directly on `Decimal` objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.sqrt). So you could write:

```
def geodetic_to_geocentric(ellps, lat, lon, h):
    a, rf = ellps
    lat_rad = radians(lat)
    lon_rad = radians(lon)
    N = a / (1 - (1 - (1 - 1 / rf) ** 2) * (sin(lat_rad)) ** 2).sqrt()
    X = (N + h) * cos(lat_rad) * cos(lon_rad)
    Y = (N + h) * cos(lat_rad) * sin(lon_rad)
    Z = ((1 - 1 / rf) ** 2 * N + h) * sin(lat_rad)

    return X, Y, Z
```

Which would yield:

```
>>> lat = Decimal('43.21009')
>>> lon = Decimal('-78.120123')
>>> h = Decimal('124')
>>> print(geodetic_to_geocentric(wgs84, lat, lon, h))
(Decimal('958506.0102730405668418845812'), Decimal('-4556367.372558064424670955239'), Decimal('4344627.161663229280843240044'))
```

Which is closer to your result than the one you expected. So I wouldn't worry in this case.

Note however that computation using `Decimal`s are usually slower

```
>>> timeit.timeit("geodetic_to_geocentric((Decimal('6378137'), Decimal('298.257223563')), Decimal('43.21009'), Decimal('-78.120123'), Decimal('124'))", setup='from __main__ import geodetic_to_geocentric_decimal as geodetic_to_geocentric; from decimal import Decimal')
86.26855880199582
>>> timeit.timeit("geodetic_to_geocentric((6378137, 298.257223563), 43.21009, -78.120123, 124)", setup='from __main__ import geodetic_to_geocentric')
1.40149550899514
```

---

Lastly, since you cache values of angles in radian, you could as well store some other values that you compute twice in variable. This includes:

- `sin(lat_rand)`
- `cos(lat_rand)`
- `(1 - 1 / rf) ** 2`

And talking about variables, you could make an effort to improve naming a bit. Some variable names may make sense to you as they may be usual in your domain; but `rf`, `ellps` or `N` doesn't convey much meaning to me, for instance.

Comment: thanks for the advice. I always thought caching a value did not retain as much precision as doing the computation each time. With regards to variable naming, fair enough remark, but I think `a` for semi major axis and `rf` for reciprocal flattening are pretty standard notations (they are the `proj4` parameters for instance) for ellipsoid parameters.

Comment: @YeO If they are standard notation for your domain, then it might be fine, it's just that I know very few of it and these names don't "speak" to me.

Comment: @YeO: In Python it makes no difference whether you assign an intermediate value to a variable or not; the value is the same whether or not you give it a name.

Comment: @GarethRees thanks for this clarification! It's very good to know.